# How do I change the fade color of the Windows 7 Login Screen?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I've customized my Windows 7 Login Screen with a custom background, that is mostly block colour save for a logo. This color is not black. The fade out of the loin screen and fade in of the desktop, is black.

I'd like to change the fade transition color to match my Login Screen primary color.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to change the actual color in the Executable or DLL responsible for switching.

Also, you need to bypass the code signing protection to be able to get the new Executable/DLL to load...

Comment: So I have an evening of hex editing ahead of me? How would one bypass the code signing protection?

Comment: @Tom: For an example of how this would be done with a BSOD, look into [this detailed article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2010/12/14/3374820.aspx). I don't know if literally black is used in your case, they could as well be decreasing the color values for the whole screen as in turning the brightness on and off this it might be way different. I believe that in 32-bit it's possible, while in 64-bit you are stuck with [Kernel Patch Protection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsvistasecurity/archive/2006/08/11/695993.aspx) of which I know no way on how to disable it...

Comment: @TomJNowell: There are methods available but I doubt it is legal to share them and whether they are already patched, I would discourage you from taking this attempt as you'll lose quite some time on it. Perhaps there is a way to disable the fade instead? Like [disabling TMM](http://www.tomstricks.com/how-to-disable-or-enable-the-transient-multimon-manager-tmm-in-windows-vista/)?